# conditional expression "? :" compiles despite branches returning different types

Tags: java, ternary-operator

I've started to learn java and I'm confrunting with the following conditional expression:

```
 ((1<2)?5:(3<4))
```

In the book where I've found this example it says that it's a syntax error because it can't convert a numerical value to a boolean one.
Same pages after, there is a test with different exercises, including this one.After writing and compiling in eclipse it gives me the output 5.
Why? I've read some things about this operator and it clearly says that the both of the expressions must be booleans or arithmetics, so it's a problem with eclipse?

Comment: 1<2 returns a boolean result, it's not a numerical value.

Comment: @LaurentiuL. `3<4` is a boolean but `5` is numerical

Comment: Can you ahow the complete line of code? it depends on the left-hand side operator if it is compileable.

Comment: @FastSnail sure, might as well be if used in the right context.

Comment: `After writing and compiling in eclipse it gives me the output 5. Why?` If you got that to compile then please show us the exact code you wrote.

Comment: @Thomas, it will work if you assign it to a suitable class (Object). `Object i = ((1<2)?5:(3<4));`

Comment: @Codebender correct, I assumed he used something like that. Just given the expression it seems as if it shouldn't work, that's why the exact code would be needed to explain the difference, i.e. the use of autoboxing.

Comment: It is certainly not a syntax error. The rule mentioned is not a syntactic rule, it is a semantic rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only "problem" with this ternary operator is that it return different types.

Let's unwrap it with `if` conditions in pseudo-code:

```
((1<2)?5:(3<4))

if (1 < 2) {
    // returns int
    return 5;
}
else {
    // either returns boolean (true)
    if (3 < 4) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

So the expression can be valid in certain conditions.

For instance, `Object o = ((1<2)?5:(3<4));` will compile fine (with warnings on the `3 < 4` part), because an `Object` can be boxed from both primitives `boolean` and `int`.

Answer (score 14):

when they talked of compiler error case that would be something like this

```
int a= ((1<2)?5:(3<4));
```

but as (3<4) returns boolean it cant be assigned to integer variable

but when you simply do `System.out.println(((1<2)?5:(3<4)));` it doesn't have to assign the value to any variable,and it prints the output value using the method `System.out.println(Object)`

if you would change the expression a bit and do :- `System.out.println(((1>2)?5:(3<4)))` then it would print `true` as output

Comment: Actually, `Object o = (1<2)?5:(3<4);` would work since due to autoboxing you can get objects from both branches. That's why printing the result to System.out works (which btw is also an assignment - to a parameter).

Comment: @Thomas yes sure it will work, but the QO wants to understand what he/she read in the book ,and why it was contradicting, so I just tried to explain that thing

Comment: No problem, I just wanted to point out why it still works, i.e. autoboxing plays a part in that as well.

Answer (score 11):

The conditional operator has three operands - the first is the condition, and the second and third are separate "branches" as it were. Which branch is evaluated depends on whether the condition evaluates to true or false.

In your case, you have:

- Condition: `1 < 2`
- Branch1: `5`
- Branch2: `3 < 4`

Now the problem is that the two branches are of different types here, so there's no useful primitive result type of the expression. It's (surprisingly, IMO) valid, with an overall expression type of `Object` - basically, both branches involve boxing. So this:

```
Object o = 1 < 2 ? 5 : 3 < 4;
```

is equivalent to:

```
Object o = 1 < 2 ? (Integer) 5 : (Boolean) (3 < 4);
```

That's specified in [JLS 15.25](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25) - your situation is shown in "Table 15.25-B. Conditional expression type (Primitive 3rd operand, Part II)" which shows that when the third operand has a type of `boolean` and the second has a type of `int`, the result is `lub(Integer,Boolean)` - basically `Object`.

Now this would be fine:

```
int x = 1 < 2 ? 5 : 4; // Both branches are of type int
```

And so would this:

```
// Very confusing with all these conditions, but valid!
boolean y = 1 < 2 ? 5 < 6 : 3 < 4; // Both branches are of type boolean
```

... but your current situation has one branch of type `int`, and one of type `boolean`.

Answer (score 2):

If you pass it to `System.out.println()` it will not complain because all values are converted to String.

So,

```
System.out.println((1<2) ? 5 : (3<4));
//Will print 5

System.out.println((3<2) ? 5 : (3<4));
//Will print true
```

But,

```
int i = ((3<2) ? 5 : (3<4));
```

or

```
boolean b = ((3<2) ? 5 : (3<4));
```

will result in a compilation error.

Answer (score 2):

Since in an `a?b:c` expression, the types of `b` and `c` can be different, the Java compiler has to try to infer the return type of the expression, to find a type that fits both operands.

This is done by looking at the type tree and finding the closest common ancestor. For reference types, this closest common ancestor is `Object` in a worst case scenario. `(1 > 2) ? new StringBuilder() : new ArrayList();` will have a return type `Object`, so if you want to assign it to a variable of type `Object` (or pass it to a method that expects a parameter of `Object` type), it's fine. Otherwise you'll get a compile error because there's no guarantee that the result can be cast to any other type.

Where your scenario is slightly more complicated is that it features primitives as `b` and `c`: an `int` and `boolean`. These will have to be auto-boxed to `Integer` and `Boolean` first, then the process above runs as normal, the return type is `Object`. But if you want to assign an `Object` to an `int`, that won't work, hence why `int x = ((1<2)?5:(3<4));` will fail to compile but `Object x = ((1<2)?5:(3<4));` will be valid.

*Note: in practice it's slightly even more complicated by the fact that there could be multiple, unrelated common ancestors, but that doesn't change the basic principle.*

Answer (score 1):

The statement by itself will not give any compilation error but the result of the conditional statement cannot be assigned to a variable because if the condition is true(as in the current case) the result will be 5 which is an Integer but if the condition is false then the result will be true which is a Boolean.

So to get the compilation error do the below,

```
Integer a = ((1>2)?5:(3<4));
```

or

```
Boolean a = ((1>2)?5:(3<4));
```

Just for the sake of making the code to compile we can assign the result to a base class.

```
Serializable a = ((1>2)?5:(3<4));
```

or

```
Object a = ((1>2)?5:(3<4));
```

Answer (score 0):

`?` is a **ternary operator** as detailed in [JSL (§15.25)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25):

```
variable = condition ? value if true : value if false;
```

Example

```
String isFalse = 3 < 4 ? "true" : "false";  // false
String isTrue  = 3 == 3 ? "true" : "false";  // true
```

**The type of a conditional expression is determined as follows:**

- If the second and third operands have the same type (which may be the null type), then that is the type of the conditional expression.
- If one of the second and third operands is of primitive type T, and the type of the other is the result of applying boxing conversion (§5.1.7) to T, then the type of the conditional expression is T.
- If one of the second and third operands is of the null type and the type of the other is a reference type, then the type of the conditional expression is that reference type.
- Otherwise, if the second and third operands have types that are convertible (§5.1.8) to numeric types, then there are several cases:

Now, knowing this and translating your expression:

```
((1<2)?5:(3<4))
```

You get `1<2=false` and `3<4=false`

```
false ? 5 : false
```

So if you try to assign a variable

```
boolean var = false ? 5 : false
int     var = false ? 5 : false
```

You will have the *syntax error because it can't convert a numerical value to a boolean one*:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object&Comparable<?>&Serializable to int<br>
                                   ↑ (3<4)                              ↑ variable assigned
```

Comment: Good job quoting the JLS, but you should also quote the relevant parts under "The type of a conditional expression is determined as follows: ...".

Comment: I never said this @EJP if you look I quoted OP phrase and noted is a TypeMismatch...

Answer (score 0):

The following compiles and runs correctly, no matter what the values of `x` and `y` are. You get either the number 5 or the boolean true. There's no problem since the result isn't assigned anywhere (or rather the result is an `Object` passed to `println(Object o)`).

```
    int x = 1;
    int y = 2;
    System.out.println(x<y ? 5 : 3<4);
```

The problem comes with assignments.

```
    int x = 1;
    int y = 2;
    int a = x<y ? 5 : 3<4;  // Won't compile without a cast to int, if x > y, results in a `ClassCastException`.
```

So while it's possible to have different types as the result, it's not necessarily a good idea. They both need to be assignable to the result, so the following will always work, no matter what is returned from either statement.

```
Object o = x < y ? "String object" : new ArrayList();  // Works since the return type is compatible
```

Answer (score 0):

3<4 will return boolean. Not int.

1<2 ? yes, then print 5
But if you will change "<" to ">" you will get "true".